# How to use $first in angular ng-repeat to insert a new table row

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to get a google map for an address in my angular application.  I'm pretty sure the issue is with the async properties of HTML & JS, but i'm not sure how to remedy that in this situation. The issue is that while the map is visually loading under the first customer address, the map points to the last address in the list.

EX:

```
123 test drive
#Map gets inserted here, but is for 789 test drive
456 test drive
789 test drive
```

The directive is as follows:

```
app.directive('addressBasedGoogleMap', function() {
    var linkFunction = function(scope, element, attrs) {
        var googleAddress = scope.$eval(attrs.address);
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder(); 
        geocoder.geocode({ 'address': googleAddress}, function (results, status){ 
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) { 
                var mapOptions = { zoom: 16, center:results[0].geometry.location, mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP}
                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('addressMap'), mapOptions); 
                var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
                       position: results[0].geometry.location,
                       map: map,
                       title: googleAddress
                     });
            }
            else{
                alert(status)
            }
        })
    };
    return {
        template : "<div id='addressMap' style='width: 500px; height:500px;'></div>",
        link: linkFunction
    };
});
```

My HTML code:

```
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat-start = "customerOrder in CustomerOrders | orderBy: '-timeEntered'">
            <td>{{customerOrder.timeEntered | date:'MM/dd/yyyy @ h:mma'}}</td>
            <td>{{customerOrder.address}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-show="$first">
            <td colspan="6" address-based-google-map address="'{{customer.address}}'"></td>
        <tr ng-repeat-end></tr>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

Comment: the map doesn't belong in `ng-repeat` ... is showing last address because of that, each iteration you pass in  new address. Take a look at using angular-map

Comment: @charlietfl I want a map for each address though, how would I go about that if I can't do it in ng-repeat?

Comment: ok...I misunderstood. You can't repeat ID's in a page though and you have hard coded ID for `new google.maps` and in template

Comment: @charlietfl good point... do you know how to do soemthing like    `template : "<div id='addressMap{{googleAddress}}' style='width: 500px; height:500px;'></div>"` ?

Comment: I would use `$index` as suffix instead. You don't want special characters in ID's. Pass as attribute to directive

Comment: What's best is to not use `id`s at all. Instead of doing a `getElementById` in your `link` function, simply use the `element` parameter of the directive because that's the one you actually target! `new google.maps.Map(element[0], mapOptions);`

Comment: can I pass scope attributes into the return?  How do I get attrs.index into the template?

Comment: Bah I let @charlietfl answer and get credits as he got the original issue about duplicating ids.

Answer (score 1):

`ng-show` only controls if HTML will be visible, it is still added to the DOM. Directive you are looking for is `ng-if`.

Comment: I understand that, however I want the map to be generated for ALL addresses, but only showing by default for the first

Comment: In this case, you need to assign different IDs to your maps DIVs. otherwise you'll end up with multiple <div id='addressMap'> elements in your page. Just add another attribute similar to address one, like mapsId="'addressMap{{$index}}'" and then use it in your div.

Comment: another option if you don't actually need this ID is change your line var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('addressMap'), mapOptions); to var map = new google.maps.Map(element[0], mapOptions);

Comment: @SSH haha I posted the same in OP answer. It's the proper angular way to do it indeed, when directives only interact with their own element, without getElementById and the like.